# PopBackStack previous last fragment and check which fragment it is

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I got a few fragments in MainActivity which can be selected from Navigation Drawer. Now, whenever users press a profile button, it will jumps to UserProfile Fragment. If home button is pressed, it will pop back the last fragment. Since I've assigned each of the fragments a specific backstack name i.e `.addToBackStack("abc")`, how can I check what is the last fragment by using `popBackStack()` method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the last fragment:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
int lastFragEntry = fm.getBackStackEntryCount()-1;
String lastFragTag = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(lastFragEntry).getName();

Log.i("Last Fragment Tag->", lastFragTag);
```

**NB:** If you want to get the name/tag of last fragment, you also have to use the same **Tag** during fragment **transaction**:

```
ft.replace(android.R.id.container, fragment, "abc");
ft.addToBackStack("abc");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me :D

Comment: My pleasure.  :)